# Get-Service on multiple remote machines

Tags: powershell

I can only get the command to return the services on the first computer in the text file.
Is there a better way than for-each for this task?

```
Get-Service *vault* -ComputerName (Get-Content c:\users\sean\desktop\js.txt) | select name,status,machinename | sort machinename | format-table -autosize
```

Answer (score 6):

Try it without the `get-content`.  Try this:

```
Get-Service *vault* -ComputerName c:\users\sean\desktop\js.txt | select name,status,machinename | sort machinename | format-table -autosize
```

If that doesn't work, then try:

```
$Computers = Get-Content c:\users\sean\desktop\js.txt
Get-Service *vault* -computername $Computers | Select name,status,machinename |sort machinename |format-table -autosize
```

If you are eager for a one-liner then try this:

```
Get-Content c:\users\sean\desktop\js.txt | Get-Service *vault* | Select name,status,machinename |sort machinename |format-table -autosize
```

I would try the top one first.  I would test, but I don't have access to anything I can do a proper test right now.

Comment: The second one works but the output stops at the first computer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How is the text file organized?  Is it Server1,Server2,Server3?

Comment: Just one per line and I checked to make sure there weren't any spaces. When I run it with the "test-connection" command it works and pings each server.

Comment: Even typing it like this `Get-Service *vault* -ComputerName MSS-EVjs-A-003,MSS-EVjs-A-001 | select machinename,name` Only returns 003 not 001

Comment: Solution 1+3 doesn't work in any PowerShell-Version. Solution 2 is exactly what OP uses just refactored, which doesn't work in PS 2.0 (only 3.0+).

Answer (score 3):

```
$Computers = get-content .\desktop\test.txt
$Service = "Vault"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
   $computer 

   $Servicestatus = get-service -name $Service -ComputerName $computer


}


$Servicestatus | select-object Name,Status,MachineName | format-table -Autosize
```

This works for me, it gives me each of the computers in the text file, and it looks for the service.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use.  I get the list of computers from an OU in AD.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ou = "OU=Servers,DC=Domain,DC=com"

$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $ou | select-object -expandproperty name

Foreach ($server in $servers){

    $Data = Get-Service -ServiceName *IIS*,*TomCat*,*httpd* -ComputerName $server | select machinename,name | sort machinename | format-table -AutoSize 

    Write($Data) | Out-File .\WebServices.txt -Append

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$servers = Get-Content .\servers.txt
Foreach ($server in $servers) {
  "$server"
  Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -name -like "*vault*"
  "-------------------"
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! While the answer includes the code snippet, some brief explanation of the code is always useful. Please try to add more detail, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Following a memory limitation limit with older versions of PowerShell, I was required to refresh my code:

**Old code:**
gwmi win32_service -computer $allcomputers | Select-Object __SERVER,Name,state,startmode,StartName

**New code:**

`$servers = Get-Content "computers.txt"
Foreach ($server in $servers) {

Get-WmiObject -Class WIN32_service -ComputerName $server |
Select-Object __SERVER,Name,state,startmode,StartName | 
Export-Csv -path "Report.CSV" -NoTypeInformation -Append

}`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get list of all services in your AD domain:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like “Windows 10*”} | ForEach-Object {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Computer $_.Name}
```

More useful examples on this (get list of services for all computer listed in a text file, etc.):
https://www.action1.com/kb/list_of_services_on_remote_computer.html

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Service -ComputerName ...` has a bug in PowerShell 2.0 that only returns the first computer. This is fixed in newer versions so if you upgrade to PowerShell 3.0 or newer, your original code will work fine.

As a workaround, use a foreach-loop to run `Get-Service` once for each computer:

```
Get-Content c:\users\sean\desktop\js.txt |
ForEach-Object { Get-Service -Name *vault* -ComputerName $_ } |
Select-Object -Property Name, Status, MachineName |
Sort-Object -Property MachineName |
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score -1):

Nick's solution totally doesn't work for me. I ended up writing a quick and dirty one that works:

```
$servers = Get-Content .\servers.txt
Foreach ($server in $servers) {
"$server"
Get-Service *vault*
"-------------------"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
GET Microsoft Windows SERVICES STATUS status information from txt file.

VERSION 1.7
Date: 3/13/2024

.NOTES
******* Customized by Mike B.*******
#>

# Start transcript to capture script output **** testing this line
$transcriptPath = "C:\temp\Log$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss')).txt" #EDIT HERE ********************
Start-Transcript -Path $transcriptPath -Force

$servers = Get-Content "path.txt" ## EDIT HERE ************************
$outputFile = "path.csv"

$results = foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Write-Host "Checking services on $server..."
    $stoppedServices = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -ComputerName $server | Where-Object { $_.State -ne "Running" }
    foreach ($stoppedService in $stoppedServices) {
        $serviceName = $stoppedService.Name
        $serviceDisplayName = (Get-Service -Name $serviceName).DisplayName  # Get the display name
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Server = $server
            Service = $serviceName
            DisplayName = $serviceDisplayName  # Add the display name to the output
            Status = $stoppedService.State
            StartType = $stoppedService.StartMode
            #Description = $stoppedService.Description
        }
    }
}

# Display the results in a grid view
#$results | Select-Object Server, Service, DisplayName, Status, StartType, Description | Out-GridView
$results | Select-Object Server, Service, DisplayName, Status, StartType | Out-GridView

# Export the results to a CSV file
$results | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation

# Stop the transcript
Stop-Transcript

# Send an email notification # EDIT HERE
Send-MailMessage -From "youremail@contoso.com" -To "youremail@contoso.com" -Subject "Services Status - PROD Servers - Services Status on servers" -Body "INFORMATION" -SmtpServer "your_mail_server" -Port 25 -Attachments $outputFile, $transcriptPath
```